# if $A\in M_{n×n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ and self-adjoint then $\exists t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A-tI$ is a negative-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if $A$ is self-adjoint then all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real.And also $A$ is unitary diagonalization over the complex numbers. Therefore $A$ has a bases $B=\{v_1, v_2,..., v_n\}$ of eigenvectors of $A$.

I would like to know please how to use this information and proceed with the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $B$ is negative-definite if and only if

$$\langle Bv, v\rangle < 0$$

for all $v\neq 0$. With $B=A-tI$ we get

$$\langle Av, v\rangle -t\langle v, v\rangle < 0.$$

Now, using the operator norm (where the ambient space has the usual Euclidean norm) we have

\begin{align}
\langle Av, v\rangle -t\langle v, v\rangle
&\leqslant
\lVert A\rVert_{op}\,\lVert v\rVert^2 - t\lVert v\rVert^2
\\&=
\lVert v\rVert^2\left(\lVert A\rVert_{op} - t\right)
\end{align}

It is well known, and a good exercise, to show that $\lVert A\rVert_{op}^2 = \max\{|\lambda|\,;\, \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of $A$}\}$.

Comment: You started from a false statement.  $B$ is negative-definite if and only if $\langle Bv, v \rangle <0$.  Given that the standard inner product is positive definite, $\langle Bv, Bv \rangle \geq 0$ regardless of what $B$ is.

Comment: @Aaron That was a gross oversight. Thank you for this observation, I've fixed it.

Comment: one second. what if the $||A||^{2}=trace(A^{2})$  , how can you conclude that it less than or equals to the largest eigenvalue of A ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of operator norm? We have $\lVert A \rVert_{op} = \sup \{\lVert Av\rVert\,;\, \lVert v \rVert = 1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $Av=\lambda v$, then $(A-tI)v=(\lambda-t)v$.

Now, since $A$ has finitely many real eigenvalues, it has a maximum eigenvalue.